# Passing info between two classes of the same DLL but without Global, Public variables

Tags: c#

When a dialog shows in my form, it can be opened from two different call stacks, either from a right click menu option or from a Menu command. And they are different ( one is creating a new report field and the other shows the properties of the current report field) So the data I populate in the fields of that form are different but somewhere in the way, they are using some common methods too.
So I wanted a way to pass the information to the `PopulateFields()` method so it knows if it has been called from the Right-Click of properties window or from the Insert Menu option.

So in the lowest level class I created a public enumaration like this to know where is it being called from so at the end the `PopulateFields()` know how to populate the fields depending on where is it comign from, as you see the call stack goes to different classes so I had to define my enumeration as public. So Public global variable? meh! That's what I would like to change, so it won't be public anymore. What is a better solution? Maybe instead of defining it in that class I can create a separate class for this enum? Is that better?

```
public enum FieldDialogSource
{
    FromPropertiesWindow,
    FromInsertMenu
}

public FieldDialogSource FieldDialogLaunchSource { get; set; }

MyLibrary.FieldDlgController.PopulateFields()
MyLibrary.frmMyForm.Init()
MyLibrary.frmMyForm.ShowForm()
MyLibrary.FieldDlgController.ShowForm()
MyLibrary.Controller.FiledProperties()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define the enumeration inside the form class (since it does belong to the form)

On the other hand, passing on "from where" a form is opened might not be considered good practice. What if you would suddenly allow your users to also use the right-click to open the form in a different state or what if there needs to be added a third source to open the form (in one of the two existing states)...

Perhaps you could overload your constructor:

- Parameterless constructor: We need to open the form in "creation mode".
- Constructor with data: Open the form in "view mode" and show the properties.

You could still use the enumeration and the property as private in the form so that all methods know at all points which constructor was called (and thus whether we are creating a new report or are viewing an existing one)
This enum could then be defined as (for example):

```
private enum FormState
{
    Insert,
    ViewData
}
```

This would be more generic than the "Source".